# Without using API gateway how can I get the URL for testing the lambda function developed in JAVA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS lambda and want to know if it's feasible to test Lambda functions developed in JAVA using URLs if we don't wanna use AWS API Gateway.

Lambda function is giving me some records. I want to route those records to a URL.

Comment: What else would you like to use?  Custom code running on an EC2 for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is. A Lambda function has no public endpoint. You need to connect it to something like a API Gateway, SNS Topic or others. There are a lot of options here. You can test a lambda manual by pressing the test button if you are in de AWS web interface. (Go to Lambda -> Click on your function -> check the upper right for the test button). You can use a predefined request or create your own.

A better solution is to test the function before it is even deployed. Just write unit tests and integrate that in your CI/CD system. If you need a actual running lambda function locally or in your CI/CD environment for integration testing I would suggest using [AWS SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html) to help you do that.